# mod_rewrite doesn't work in public folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my dir:

```
root/
├── app/
├── public/
|       ├── css/
|       ├── img/
|       ├── index.php
|       ├── .htaccess
├── .htaccess
```

I want every request to the `root/` folder to be rewritten to the `public/` folder, and then pass the url to `index.php` through a `$_GET` variable.
This is my `root/.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

This is my `root/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

There is no `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` because I don't want the user to see the directories, for example: `root/css`.
When I go to `root/app` it works fine and I get `$_GET['url'] = 'app'`. But when I go to `root/public` I don't get `$_GET['url'] = public`; instead, it shows me the directory structure of the `public` folder. And when I go to `root/public/` (note the trailing slash), it takes me to `root/public/index.php` and it doesn't pass the variable as well.
I would be thankful if you could tell me how to fix that. I want `root/public` to rewrite to `root/public/index.php?url=public`.
**EDIT:** Also when I go to `root/public/css` it returns `$_GET['url'] = 'css'` instead of `$_GET['url'] = 'public/css'`. It seems that when the `public` folder is accessed, it ignores the first `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you've turned off `DirectorySlash`. See the [apache documentation for mod_dir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

> **Security Warning**
>
> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where *mod_autoindex* is active (`Options +Indexes`) and `DirectoryIndex` is set to a valid resource (say, `index.html`) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html file. **But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.**

Since "public" is a directory, when you request `/public` it won't get routed to public via the root's htaccess file, it will get served by mod_autoindex before mod_rewrite even gets a chance to process it.

So you need to turn directory slash back **ON** (or just comment out that line, since it's on by default), then change your rules in the public directory to remove trailing slashes, as well as handle the blank request (e.g. for `/public/`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?url=public [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

EDIT:

> If I remove `DirectorySlash off`, when I go to `root/css` it redirects me to `root/public/css/?url=css`. I have to keep it in order to prevent that from happening.

Then what you need to do is handle everything from the root htaccess file and route *before* any actual directories get examined. So remove or comment out the `RewriteEngine On` in your public directory and change the rules in your root directory to:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteRule ^public/?$ /public/index.php?url=public [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /public/index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: If I remove `DirectorySlash off`, when I go to `root/css` it redirects me to `root/public/css/?url=css`. I have to keep it in order to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @user2597040 Sorry, I had edited my answer but never hit "Submit"

Answer (score 0):

When the `public` folder is accessed it jumps away to the `root/public/.htaccess` file, ignoring the `root/.htaccess` file. To prevent that from happening I used only one `.htaccess` file in the `root` directory:

```
# Prevent redirection to directory: 'root/css' won't turn into 'root/public/css?url=css'
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine on

# When 'root/css', 'root/img' or 'root/js' is accessed, return the real path 'root/public/css/...'
RewriteRule ^((css|img|js)/(.+))$ public/$1 [END]
# For all the requests just pass the u
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,END]
```